# To what points can $f(x,y)=\frac{x^{5}}{\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}y}$ be extended by continuity?

Tags: limits, continuity

Considering the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^{5}}{\sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}y }$, I found that its domain $D_f$ is:

$D_f = \mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash  \{k\cdot \pi \;|\; k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \times\{k\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \;|\; k \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}\}$.

I am looking for all the points $a \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash D_f$ to which $f$ can be extended by continuity.

The problem is that I get stuck when trying to compute limits since both the nominator and denomnator go to $0$, are there any identities I am missing?

Comment: For those points not in $D_f$ where the nominator does **not** tend to $0$, can you decide if it is extensible there? For the other case, do you know what $\lim_{x \to 0}(\sin(x)/x)$ is?

Comment: Thanks! So I found that in the first case (when the denominator does not tend to $0$), that  the function wasn't extensible because the limit goes to plus infinity. But in the second case, by using l'Hopital rule, I found that it was extensible since the limit was $0$.